# Java Incompatible Types error after placing classes into a package

Tags: java, package, javac, incompatibletypeerror

I have a package named "shapefile" which contains classes IndexFileReader and IndexFile. IndexFileReader returns an object of type IndexFile.

I then have a class named ReadFiles which imports "shapefile" and uses IndexFileReader to create an IndexFile.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import shapefile.*;
public class ReadFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        IndexFile indexFile;
        indexFile = IndexFileReader.readIndexFile("FilePath/FileName.shx");
    }
}
```

My files are located in folders as follows:

- JavaProjects

  - shapefile

    - IndexFileReader.java
    - IndexFile.java
  - MyProject

    - ReadFiles.java

I compile the shapefile project from the Windows command line like this and it compiles fine:

```
cd JavaProjects
javac .\shapefile\*.java
```

I compile my project like this and I get an error:

```
cd MyProject
javac -cp .. ReadFiles.java
```

Error:

```
ReadFiles.java:8: error: incompatible types
            indexFile = IndexFileReader.readIndexFile("FilePath/FileName.shx");
                                                     ^
required: IndexFile
found:    shapefile.IndexFile
```

This is new to me and I believe I am doing something wrong with running javac. I have successfully compiled ReadFiles previously, I thought I did so with the same commands I've printed here. I actually still have the ReadFiles.class file from when this compiled successfully and it runs without any problems, which is why I believe I am not using javac correctly.

1. Why is Java giving an error after requiring an object of "IndexFile" and receiving an object of "shapefile.IndexFile"? Aren't these objects the same type?
2. Why is my IndexFileReader class returning an object of type "shapefile.IndexFile" instead of an object of type "IndexFile"?
3. Is there anything with how I have my files/folders laid out that will cause problems with compiling?
4. What command to I provide Windows to correctly use javac to compile my package and to compile my ReadFiles class?

I have looked through the other Incompatible Types questions and I have not found one that had led me in the right direction.

Comment: You probably also copied `IndexFile.java` to your `MyProject` directory, and you still have it there, or you still have the compiled `IndexFile.class` still there.

Comment: That is what I think. Make sure IndexFile is not in your MyProject directory.

Comment: But don't use this structure of folders and packages. Either declare your `class ReadFiles` to be in package `MyProject`, or move the directory `MyProject` one level up until it is a sibling of `JavaProjects`. With your current setup you are setting yourself up for many problems.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. The problem was in fact that there was already an "IndexFile.class" file in the JavaProjects folder. It was left over from before I placed the files into a package.

I have placed my files into a more standard folder structure as suggested and everything is running ok.